# Excel - Comparing values from 2 columns, to 2 other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My question is giving me some trouble.  I am trying to compare an origin zip code and destination zip code, with another origin zip code and destination zip code.

An example would be Origin: 63304, Destination: 56687

I want to be able to find out if this origin and destination combination exists in a different list.

[image]

In the image you can see that I have the first two origin and destination zip codes, then a space, then there are another combination of origin and destination zip codes.

How can I compare columns L&M with O&P to see if that combination shows up anywhere in either list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=CONCATENATE(L1,M1) in N1
=CONCATENATE(O1,P1) in Q1
```

Autofill for all existing rows and then copy all results in N and Q column, put them together in one column and simply remove duplicates (you will get info with number of deleted records) or highlight duplicates (via conditional formatting).

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX($L:$M,MATCH($O2,$L:$L,0),2)=$P2,FALSE),"Match","No Match")
```

Put this formula into Q2, and drag down. This will return "Match" or "No Match" depending on if the same combination in columns O & P is found in L & M.

Comment: This almost works, I am getting 22 matches when there should be about 660, is there anything that may be missing here?

Comment: Are you wanting to check for matches within both lists? This formula only looks for match of O&P in L&M.

Comment: Or are you looking for a count?

Comment: I am looking to check for matches in both list, for example in list 1: origin is 63304 and destination is 45505, if that combination appears anywhere else in the list, I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

A simple concanetate comparison should suffice. In Q2:

```
=AND(L:L&M:M = O:O&P:P)
```

Will return True if the combination of L and M matches a combination of O and P. Careful though, a simple space at the end or beginning of a postal code will throw the comparison off. If you worry about that, you can use the `trim()` function for each of your references inside the `And()`.

Comment: I am getting FALSE as every return on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS($L:$L,$O2,$M:$M,$P2)+COUNTIFS($O:$O,$O2,$P:$P,$P2)
```

Try this one instead. I think this matches what you are wanting now that I understand more.